# Java inherance method with return type

Tags: java, inheritance, review

Is it correct to write my classes like this? In question is the method `getPrice()` in the `Item` class. Every Item needs to have a `getPrice()`. But I can't actually return something. So I fire the `this.getPrice()` with gets me the Price of the `ProductItem`. Is there a more solid / better designed solution?

```
class Item {
    String description;

    public Item(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    double getPrice(){return this.getPrice();} //TODO Correct like this?
}

class ProductItem extends Item {
    int amount;
    double pricePerUnit;

    public ProductItem(String description, int amount, double pricePerUnit)         {
        super(description);
        this.amount = amount;
        this.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;
    }

    @Override
    double getPrice(){
        return amount * pricePerUnit;
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.getPrice()` doesn't exist in `Item`. You just need to do `return 0`. The overriden class returns the correct thing as it is `overriden`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like `Item` should be an abstract class then, with `getPrice()` being an abstract method:

```
public abstract class Item {
    private final String description;

    public Item(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public abstract double getPrice();

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

That means you won't be able to write

```
Item item = new Item("foo"); // Invalid, because Item is abstract
```

But you can write:

```
Item item = new ProductItem("foo", 10, 2.0);
double p = item.getPrice(); // 20.0
```

Every concrete (non-abstract) subclass you declare will have to override `getPrice()` and provide an implementation.

See the [abstract classes and methods section of the Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

What you have to do is make your `Item` class `abstract`, by making the `getPrice` method abstract.

This forces your subclasses to implement the specific function, if they don't the compiler will give an error.

You can do this as follows:

```
class Item {
    String description;

    public Item(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    abstract double getPrice();
}
```

The implementation you give actually causes a circular (infinite loop) call to itself when the subclass has forgotten to implement the function. When the subclass has implemented the function it is never called at all, because it is override by the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you make `getPrice()` and `Item` class [abstract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html), as follows:

```
  public abstract class Item {
    private String description;

    public Item(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    protected abstract double getPrice();

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

And provide the implementation in the class extending the same as follows:

```
public class ProductItem extends Item {
    private int amount;
    private double pricePerUnit;

    public ProductItem(final String description, final int amount, final double pricePerUnit) {
        super(description);
        this.amount = amount;
        this.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;
    }

    @Override
    protected double getPrice() {
        return amount * pricePerUnit;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in-case you missed it, there is problem with class `Item` where the method `getPrice()` is recursive. So here `new Item().getPrice()` will result into StackOverflowException.

You could made the class as abstract.

```
abstract class Item {
  String description;
  public Item(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }
  abstract double getPrice(); // force child classes to override this method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`double getPrice(){return this.getPrice();}` is basically an infinite loop.
You should set that price first.

```
class Item {
    String description;
    double price;
    public Item(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    double getPrice(){return this.price;} 
}
```